# Can any request be completed though Mission Replays?

Tags: final-fantasy-type-0-hd

So looking at some of the requests i can get in Akademia they seem to be wanting me to partake in battles such as killing imperial MAs and using a skill to make so many skills.

One of the Requests i can find in the Lounge was asking for SPP and there was a note saying that SPP gained from the Mission on the title screen counted.

Since going outside Akademia costs me 6 hours (half a day) and i have to return each time to complete the request i am wondering that if i could complete a request by doing it in a Mission Reply from the title Screen (ie. Destroy a Striker, Kill # enemies with Fire RF or with Killstrikes) would it be counted as completed when return the game?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is **Yes**.

I started my game and found the easiest request I could find. I simply needed to harvest a Red Phantoma for the Sorcery. I returned to the title screen, loaded up a mission, and completed the mission with a harvested Red Phantoma. I returned to the sorcery and the request was fulfilled.